# data-ng-trim="false" is not working in angular

Tags: angularjs

My html is 
My html is

```
<form name="signInForm" novalidate="">
<div class="form-group has-feedback has-feedback-left">
<label class="control-label sr-only">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Email address" required="" data-ng-model="user.username" data-ng-trim="false"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group clearfix">
<div class="pull-right">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" data-ng-click="signIn()">
<span class="submit-button-text">Sign in</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.signIn = function(isValid) {
    $log.log("username is" + $scope.user.username + $scope.user.password);

}
```

when I clicked sign in button  , mu user name white spaces are trim off. But I want that white spaces in my user name should retain so that I can track it and displayed error message.
So I used 'data-ng-trim = false' .
But it seems its not working.

Please help.

Comment: `ng-trim` will help you to remove whitespaces only from front and end.. to check whitespaces in between strings you need to use `ng-pattern`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there `ng-trim` doesn't apply to `input type="email"`. What you can do is change the input to `type="text"` in order to use the `ng-trim`, but this solution is not ideal.

See the [Angular documentation for `input type=email`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ng-trim="false"`:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" 
  placeholder="Email address" required="" 
  data-ng-model="user.username" 
  ng-trim="false"/>
```

If it is not working for you, please update you angularjs version here.

Comment: I already tried with ng-trim="false". But it is also not working.